# Why is this php function adding a space before my CSS ID selector?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on a multisite in which I am attempting to hide an element on one site but not the other. Since they share the same theme file, my thinking was to use the below is_english() function to assign separate CSS classes to each site, and for the Spanish site (assigned connectarse) set display: none; in the CSS.

However, using developer tools, this keeps translating as # connectarse. If I fix it in the console, then my fix works as it should. I just can't figure out why that pesky space is there in the first place.

Thank you!

PHP File

```
<div id="<?= is_english()?'connect':'connectarse'?>" class="section section-blue">
```

CSS

```
#connectarse { display: none;}
```

Website: http://adelanteemprendedora.com , I am attempting to remove blue "empieze a comprar" bar.

Comment: Thanks Arshid KV, was struggling with the formatting!

Comment: I'm looking at your code for the website and there is no extra space.

Comment: Yeah, it's working for me now too... I had cleared my cache previously to no avail, but perhaps that had something to do with it. Strange. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In css, increase `#connectarse` priority by adding parent class.

Eg:-

```
body #connectarse{
{ display: none;}
}
```

Or add `!important`

```
#connectarse{
    { 
     display: none !important;}
    }
```